# Can't access fetched data from PDO query

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, foreach

I am trying to create a dropdown-list with options (genres) from my database. For example if I have comedy, thriller and action in my database, these genres will be available as options on my dropdown-list. Basically what happens is that I get a blank list with no options and I was wondering if there is any problem with my code. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

    $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT Genre.name FROM (Genre JOIN Movie2Genre ON Genre.id = Movie2Genre.idGenre)';
    $stmt = $db3->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    $allGenre = $stmt->fetchAll();


    echo "<select>";
    foreach ($allGenre as $val){
        echo "<option value='{$val["name"]}'>{$val["name"]}</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";

?>
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: So it's working or not?

Comment: Basically it wont display anything inside the dropdown list. So I was wondering if anything is wrong with my coding.

Comment: And sorry for not writing any comments above the code. I am new to stackoverflow x) so I don't know how to add comments.

Comment: Maybe because you don't print anything ? `echo "<select>"; /* Your foreach loop, but write "echo" instead of "$genre[] = "*/ echo "</select>";`

Comment: Add a `echo  "<select>";` before the foreach and a `echo  "</select>";` after it! And change `$val` to `$val["name"]`

Comment: I changed it to echo as shown above. But it didn't solve it :)

Comment: I changed it to the code above, but I am getting the same result (empty dropdown list)

Comment: Now your are almost there you only have to change `{$val}` to `{$val["name"]}`. 1. Otherwise you would get an error if you have error reporting on: `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>` 2. Do `print_r($allGenre);` and you see why you need to change it

Comment: I changed $val now as well. And "name" is the same in my database. But it is still not showing any results. I just double checked my SQL clause and it seemed to work just fine. I would like to add that the dropdown list that is after this one (which was working) disappears when I have the php code.

Comment: `echo "<select>";` You print something! So you should see at least something!!! Are you sure you look at the right script?!?

Comment: Yes, I see the empty list. But no options. :)

Comment: Then your query fails! Try it in a `try and catch block` e.g. `try { //your code } catch(PDOException $e){ echo $e->getMessage();} //foreach loop`

Comment: Also what is the output of: `print_r($allGenre);` ? (Ah and make sure you add this after your connection: `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`)

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => comedy [0] => comedy ) [1] => Array ( [name] => romance [0] => romance ) [2] => Array ( [name] => college [0] => college ) [3] => Array ( [name] => crime [0] => crime ) [4] => Array ( [name] => drama [0] => drama ) [5] => Array ( [name] => thriller [0] => thriller ) [6] => Array ( [name] => animation [0] => animation ) [7] => Array ( [name] => adventure [0] => adventure ) [8] => Array ( [name] =>

Comment: family [0] => family ) [9] => Array ( [name] => svenskt [0] => svenskt ) [10] => Array ( [name] => action [0] => action ) [11] => Array ( [name] => horror [0] => horror ) )

Comment: The output was too long that I had to divide it into two comments ;3

Comment: I solved it! I had to replace {$val["name"]} with {$val->name} and it worked. Thank you so much for your patience and help. How do I give you a thumbs up? :=)

Comment: And you are sure you have `$allGenre = $stmt->fetchAll();` in your code?

Comment: @sekai If I am correct, your code would have worked if you had changed fetchAll() to fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC).

Comment: Yes ^^ it is correct. In my database connection file I had $db3->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ); "FETCH_OBJ" which might have caused the problem.

Comment: ^ OMG why couldn't you say that at the start?!? (Should I put an answer in?)

Comment: Hahaha I'm sorry xP next time I will. Thank you again. And yes. Please do so I can give a thumbs up.

Comment: I hope I did it right. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29333371/how-to-create-select-dropdown-with-php-edit-the-issue-was-solved-please-rea#comment46857639_29333371) you set your default fetch mode with [`setAttribute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php). So you fetch your data as an object and not as an array as it would be normal, with this:

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Also a quote from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) where it says which mode is default:

> **PDO::FETCH_BOTH (default):** returns an **array indexed by both column name and 0-indexed column number** as returned in your result set

So instead of this structure:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [0] => 1
            [number] => 3234
            [1] => 3234
            [text] => sdfdsf
            [2] => sdfdsf
            [texttext] => sdfsdf
            [3] => sdfsdf
        )
    //...
```

You have a structure like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [number] => 3234
            [text] => sdfdsf
            [texttext] => sdfsdf
        )
    //...
```

So you need to use [`->`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) to access the object property like this:

```
$val->name
```

**Side Notes:**

Also if you would have added [`error reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) (only while staging, never in production!):

```
<?php
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

You would have received an error like this:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

And I would recommend you to [enable error mode](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) for your PDO connection (just put it right after the connection statement):

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Then you can also put your db stuff in a [`try & catch`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) block to catch PDOExceptions:

```
try {
    //db stuff
} catch(PDOException) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your current code we can state that

1. <s>you are not doing anything with `$genre`</s> - you are outputting the `<option>` elements
2. there might not be any genres (i.e. `$genre` is not set)

<s>If 1 is true,</s> Consider putting the `explode`'d/joined value of `$genre` in an enclosing `<select>`<sup>[docs](https://www.google.nl/search?q=select+tag&oq=select+tag&aqs=chrome..69i57.992j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)</sup> tag.

In case of 2, the select will be empty. Because your question does not include the specific code for outputting the select, it's hard to say what is really the problem. Your question states "I can't select (drop)" so there might even be JavaScript changing the enabled-attribute of the (if any) outputted select.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. When I said that I can't select I actually meant that no options showed up :=)

Comment: $genre is not empty since I am using the exact same SQL clause elsewhere on my site.